# How to get the ordered items images in the order detail API in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, api

I need to get the product image in the order details API of the customer. Please help me to guide how can I achieve this.

Thanks in ad

Comment: to achieve this you have to create one extension attribute for each order item for every order, default order detail API will not have image information so you have to create one extension attribute

Comment: Anand Ontigeri, thanks for the response. Can you please help to share the code.